# Let $K_1, K_2$ be fields and $f: K_1 \to K_2$ Ring Homomorphism. Prove $f$ is injective or Zero Homomorphism ($f(a) = 0_{K_2}$ for all $a \in K_1$)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, group-homomorphism, ring-homomorphism

By the way, is "Zero Homomorphism" the correct translation of the German word "Nullhomomorphismus" ? When I googled, I did not find the word Null Homomorphism in English

---

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be fields, and let $f: K_1 \to K_2$ be a Ring Homomorphism. Prove that $f$ is either injective or the Zero Homomorphism ($f(a) = 0_{K_2}$ for all $a \in K_1$)

---

My attempt:
$$f: K_1 \to K_2$$
Some properties of Homomorphism are:
$$f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$$
$$f(a \cdot b) = f(a) \cdot f(b)$$

We have two cases:

Case 1, $f$ is Zero Homomorphism:

$\exists k \neq 0$ such that $f(k) = 0$

$K$ \ {$0$} is an Abelian Group.

$a \neq 0 \implies a^{-1}$ exists.

So we have:

$$f(a) = f(a \cdot k^{-1}k) = f(a)f(k^{-1})f(k) = 0$$

Case 2, $f$ is injective:

$\forall k \neq 0$ we have $f(k) \neq 0$

$$f(a) = f(b) \implies f(a) - f(b) = 0 \implies f(a-b) = 0 \implies a - b = 0 \implies a = b$$

---

Is this correct ? Did I miss or forget something ?

Comment: Your proof is the wrong way around: It is true (but trivial) that $f(a) = 0$ for any $a$ if $f$ is a zero homomorphism (which is, indeed, the correct translation), and $f(a) = f(b)$ implies $a=b$ by definition if $f$ is injective. But the claim was that _any_ ring homomorphism $f: K_1 \to K_2$ is either the zero homomorphism or injective - and this doesn't follow from your proofs at all.

Comment: Here's a hint: First, prove that for all $a \in K_1 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, $f(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1}$. Next, suppose $f$ is not a zero homomorphism, i.e., there is some $a \in K$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$. Can you prove from this that $f(x) = 0$ implies $x = 0$, or equivalently, $x \neq 0$ implies $f(x) \neq 0$?

Comment: @JohannesKloos Because $a$ is non-zero and $K_1$ is a field, $a$ has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$ in $K_1$. We know $f(1_K) = 1_K$ but we also know $f(1_K) = f(a \cdot a^{-1}) = f(a) \cdot f(a^{-1})$. This implies $1_K = f(a) \cdot f(a^{-1})$ which means $f(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1}$.  Does this look correct for now ?

Comment: @JohannesKloos Assuming my comment above is correct, if we know $f(a^{-1}) = f(a)^{-1}$, suppose $f(x) = 0$, we would need to find an inverse under Multiplication, but $0$ doesn't have a Multiplicative Inverse, so this must imply that $x = 0$ because above we assumed $a$ is non-zero. Is this correct ? If $x \neq 0$ that means we have again $f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1}$,  but we know that $0$ has no inverse so we can only have $f(x) \neq 0$, does this make sense ?

Comment: Kernels are ideals

Comment: @TonyPizza What do you mean ?

Comment: When you have homomorphism from ring to ring then kernel is ideal. Now think what are ideals of a field. That's just quick way to say what others are saying more explicitly. We are basically using the already established theory of rings and ideals to shorten our argument.

Comment: @TonyPizza I'm not sure wengen already knows about the ideals of fields at this point - this question seems to be too basic for him to be able to use the "$\ker f$ must be 0 or 1" argument.

Comment: @JohannesKloos Yes this term is not familiar to me. By the way, is my attempt in the comments above correct ?

Comment: @TonyPizza This term is not really familiar to me. By the way, is my attempt in the comments above correct ?

Comment: @JohannesKloos if one is familiar with ideals and kernels being ideals then to find ideals of fields should be very task.

Comment: @wengen you are on right track but not very precise. You say $f(x) =0$ means $ 0$ has to have inverse which is not true. What you can conclude from it is that $f(1) = f(xx^{-1})= f(x)f(x^{-1}) = 0\cdot f(x^{-1})  = 0$ From this can you say something about $f$?

Comment: @TonyPizza "if one is familiar with ..." - the keyword here being "if" :)

Comment: @TonyPizza We can write any $f(a)$ as $f(a \cdot 1) = f(a\cdot xx^{-1}) = f(a)f(x)f(x^{-1}) = f(a)\cdot 0 \cdot f(x^{-1}) = 0$ So that means any $f(a) = 0$ which means it is a zero homomorphism, is that correct ?